# Resizable Side Window

Tags: c, winapi

Is there any way to create a child window that is resizable only on the right edge and covers up a part of the left side of the parent window? Similar to that of Firefox's History panel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in one strike AFAIK. However, you can create a child window as usual and use `GetWindowRect()` to get dimensions of the bounding rectangle (in this case, we are interested in top, bottom, and right of `RECT` structure); then intercept the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message and keep monitoring the current x & y mouse coordinate from `lParam` parameter;

If current mouse position is at the right side of the window box, call `LoadCursor()` or `LoadImage()` to set the cursor shape to `IDC_SIZEWE`; then use `SetCapture()` and `ReleaseCapture()` to listen to drag-drop mouse event, and use `SetWindowPos()` to set new size of the window.